# Any way to leave PrimaryHeader blank for ShieldUI Chart without getting the "ShieldUI Chart"?

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I already have a label for my chart and don't want the default "ShieldUI Chart" to be the header for my chart. If I add my own PrimaryHeader I can get that to display, but I can't leave it blank or I get "ShieldUI Chart" in its place.

**My Header Shows Up:**

```
                <shield:ShieldChart 
                    ID="ShieldChart0" 
                    runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" Height="200px" 
                    OnTakeDataSource="ShieldChart0_TakeDataSource"> 
                    <PrimaryHeader Text="My Header Shows Up"> 
                    </PrimaryHeader> 
                    ...
                </shield:ShieldChart>
```

[image]

**'Shield UI Chart' Shows Up:**

```
                <shield:ShieldChart 
                    ID="ShieldChart0" 
                    runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" Height="200px" 
                    OnTakeDataSource="ShieldChart0_TakeDataSource"> 
                    <PrimaryHeader Text=""> 
                    </PrimaryHeader> 
                    ...
                </shield:ShieldChart>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by setting the PrimaryHeader to a blank space like this:

```
       <shield:ShieldChart 
            ID="ShieldChart0" 
            runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" Height="200px" 
            OnTakeDataSource="ShieldChart0_TakeDataSource"> 
            <PrimaryHeader Text=" "> 
            </PrimaryHeader> 
            ...
        </shield:ShieldChart>
```